# Raycasting in three.js not working properly on ipad and touch devices

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working on a [3D tool for desktop and iPad](http://54.83.230.77/BBQIsland/2.0/). Everything is working fine except for two issues:

Issue 1 - When I select a 3D object with the mouse and move it on an iPad (as opposed to on desktop, where it works just fine), it doesn't move. (You can add cabinet by selecting the cabinet panel in right).

Issue 2 - I want to spawn and drag an object with the click of a button like [this](http://outdoor.eldoradostone.com/outdoor/tool/).
With this tool, you can add an object by selecting and dragging it to the scene.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: What's your iOS version? WebGL is known not to work on iOS versions below 8. http://caniuse.com/#search=webgl

Comment: I have iOs version 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address Issue 1 - If raycasting works fine on desktop it should work fine on mobile (the THREE.js library/math code will be the same on each and runs without any sort of WebGL call as raycasting is done in the CPU in javascript).

I see though from the link that you're using `touchmove` which is correct but you're listening with your user creation function `onDocumentMouseMove` that reads `event.clientX`. This property [doesn't look to be supported on iOS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch/clientX) (See the compatibility table at the bottom).

It might be wise to use Hammer.js to normalize these events and properties into gestures for you or look into using a different property (like `.pageX`)

Comment: I have figured that out. i just have to detect the device and if it is a touch device then i have to use event.touches[0].page instead of event.client and it is working perfect. i'll definetly look into your suggestion. thanks for replying :)

Comment: Hey @coburn can you help mw out with this issue?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47280018/applying-different-textures-on-model-obj-in-three-js?noredirect=1#comment81655924_47280018